# Print value from data frame, not rownumber

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, vector, rstudio

I have a simple data frame without row names (so row number is created automatically) and just one named Column ("sec"). And I want to get the value inside the cell 1:1.

[image: This is what the dataframe looks like]

The attributes are the following:

```
$`names`
[1] "sec"

$row.names
[1] 1

$class
[1] "data.frame"
```

When I run: `secCluster[1,1]` I'am getting: `[1] hnkgisap` but when I want to assign the VALUE to a new dataframe: like: `frame[1,1] <- secCluster[1,1]` I'am just getting the 1 and nothing else.

I'am feeling very stupid for asking this question but I can't figure out whats wrong and I'am trying and googling since hours now...

Comment: It sounds like `sec` is a factor variable rather than character, so it is assigning the numeric factor level instead of the name.  Try `secCluster$sec <- as.character(secCluster$sec)` first.

Comment: Thank you! This was the Problem, and I found it out 15 seconds after I posted this question... damn.